# Does a service exist to open selected filename from the Terminal in an app?

Tags: terminal, services

I know I can do an `open -a Textmate FILE` or `open FOLDER` by typing, but is there already a text service so that a name can be Ctrl-clicked to "Open in Finder" or "Open in Editor"?

A URL can be Cmd-clicked to open in Safari, I see. Is there more stuff like that?

Comment: Well, now it does. Sorta.

Answer (score 2):

If you use iTerm (which is a great terminal), URLs and files are all openable with a cmd-click by default.

This is configurable as Semantic History - https://iterm2.com/3.2/documentation-preferences.html

Comment: Reading, yeah that's kinda how I've done it.
Terminal.app is my preferred term though.

Answer (score 0):

After two hours (not kidding) of poking and prodding I have a script and a service that do this for me:

[image: Automator Service]

Here's `cwd.scpt` that fishes out my `fish` working directory (change to `bash` if you're into that):

```
tell application "Terminal"
  do shell script "lsof -a -p `lsof -a -c fish -u $USER -d 0 -n | tail -n +2 | awk '{if($NF==\"" & (tty of front tab of front window) & "\"){print $2}}'` -d cwd -n | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $NF}'"
end tell
```

Thus I can `ls .` and ctrl-click something to "Do Open" it in `TextMate` (change to what have you). Or do the same from some command's output, and have Finder come up, or whatever.

```
CWD="`osascript $HOME/bin/cwd.scpt`"
test -d "$CWD/$@"  && open "$CWD/$@"
test -f "$CWD/$@"  && open -a TextMate "$CWD/$@"
exit 0
```

Can't say I'm happy with this, but, you know, gotta move on.
Enjoy.